# Flask Heroku psql not getting migrated despite successful local migration

Tags: heroku, psql, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli, flask-migrate

I ran into this issue earlier where despite having a migration commit & pushing it to heroku, the remote postgres didn't upgrade.

I finally found the solution to be:

```
Heroku run bash
flask db migrate
flask db upgrade
```

Aka running migrations on server. However, this strategy is no longer working.

As once I run it I get:

```
~ $ flask db migrate
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
~ $ flask db upgrade
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
```

Despite pushing the local migration commit to heroku.

P.S: I tried restarting heroku server and “heroku run rake db:migrate” for the past 3 hours. None have worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by running your `flask db init` `flask db migrate` and `flask db upgrade` on local but using the `DATABASE_URI` of the production db. This will assume you have the migration folder deleted before you do so to avoid conflicts and then push the updated version to remote.

If it trows some errors you might consider using a drop on alembic_version like this: `DROP TABLE alembic_vesion" and redo the process again.